# command line debug build project Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, i386

Running `xcodebuild -target szapp` returns:

```
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$/Users/szmall/Documents/new12/trunk/head/ShiZu -configuration Debug build -sdk iphonesimulator9.2 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO VALID_ARCHS='arm64 armv7s armv7 i386'
build my project have this error:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QQApiAudioObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSocialQQ.a(UMSocialQQHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QQApiImageObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSocialQQ.a(UMSocialQQHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QQApiInterface", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSocialQQ.a(UMSocialQQHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QQApiNewsObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSocialQQ.a(UMSocialQQHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QQApiTextObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSocialQQ.a(UMSocialQQHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QQApiVideoObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSocialQQ.a(UMSocialQQHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SendMessageToQQReq", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSocialQQ.a(UMSocialQQHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TencentOAuth", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libSocialQQ.a(UMSocialQQHandler.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

but libSocialQQ.a exist on Link Binary With Libraries.

And use xcode run my project can build success. Please help me，Thanks！

Comment: The problem has been solved. libSocialQQ.a does not contain code for i386,but it contain code for x86_64.So can use the following command line ：xcodebuild -target szapp CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$/Users/szmall/Documents/new12/trunk/head/ShiZu -configuration Debug build -sdk iphonesimulator9.2 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO VALID_ARCHS='arm64 armv7s armv7 x86_64'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `i386` from Target's Build Settings -> Architectures -> Valid Architectures, there is no need to specify it. But if your library does not contain code for `i386` - you will have problems trying to run it on older simulators.

BTW, you can check supported architectures using command `lipo -info libSocialQQ.a`.

Comment: Thank you Anton Malyshev . libSocialQQ.a donot contain code for i386.

Comment: but，why it can running in xcode's(7.2.1) simulators.

Comment: that depends on the simulator. if you choose an iPad Air or iPhone 6 Simulator for example, Xcode will build the app with x86_64 architecture.